# Possible spam emails from our server but not from our domains

Tags: centos, postfix, spam, smtp

I encountered something weird with my mail server. For about 3 days now I am noticing that my mail server sending emails that aren't included in my domains. There are from different IPs different mail server but our mail server sending these emails. I am using spam filters and spf records but still the same.

What else should I try? and what occurs these problems.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sounds like you're operating an open relay... SPF and Spam Filters are meant to combat incoming spam, not outgoing. You really should stop your mail server until you can fix the configuration. Sounds like you're running Postfix? What configuration have you changed from the defaults?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your mail server is under control of SPAMMERS , you should check your mail server for open relay.

Telnet to your mail server

$ telnet mail.myserver.com 25
Output:

Trying 202.51.x.xxx...

Connected to mail.myserver.com.

Escape character is '^]'.

220 mail.myserver.com ESMTP Postfix

helo client.server.com

250 mail.myserver.com

mail from: abhishek@xyz.com

250 Ok

rcpt to: abhishekanand1984@gmail.com

554 : Relay access denied